# Auto renew Apple Developer Program with different card

Tags: apple-id, developer-program

Does anyone know if it's possible to auto renew your Apple Developer Program with a different credit/debit card than the default one on file for your Apple ID?

Answer (score 5):

If your asking about having another *credit card* associated to your Apple Developer Program, aside from what you have defined on the ***Apple ID***, the answer is **NO**.

But if your asking about replacing the default *credit card* information for your **Apple Developer Program**, you can do the following:

- Login to your [**Apple Developer Account**](https://developer.apple.com/account/).
- Click the **`Membership`** menu.
- Scroll down to **`Settings`** section.
- Click on **`Edit default debit/credit card`**.
  [image: Edit default debit/credit card]
- and you will be directed to the [**Apple ID website**](https://appleid.apple.com/#!&page=signin).
- Go to the **`Payment and Shipping`**. and click on **`Edit`**.
- Set your desired *credit card* information.
- The **`Save`** button will be **enabled** then click it to save the changes.
  [image: Save from AppleID.com]

**Apple** will now charge the *new credit card* upon the auto-renewal process on the **Apple Developer Program** renewal date.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes, I want a different credit from the default one. I will file a bug report with Apple for this feature.